# Why adding SUM changes the number of retrieved rows?

Tags: mysql

I have this sql which gives me 6 rows without SUM clause (sur can give more if condition is true)

```
SELECT id, prodname, prodid, st_date, montant, tvaval, quantite, status, factureno
FROM StockData WHERE " + VenteWhere + " ORDER BY " + Order_by + " " + SortDir + "

PS: VenteWhere, Order_by abd SortDir are the variables.
```

BUt when I add SUM(quantite) I get only one row. Is there a way to have 6 rows data and the sum of 6 rows or I have to do another query for getting it

Comment: You want the same value for the sum in all your rows without GROUPING them (extra column)? Or do you want a final row that has the sum for all of the rows (extra-row)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use

```
 SELECT id, prodname, prodid, st_date, montant, tvaval, SUM(quantite), status, factureno
 FROM StockData 
 WHERE " + VenteWhere + " 
 ORDER BY " + Order_by + " " + SortDir + "
 GROUP BY xxxxx
```

Where  xxxxx  represents the variable you want to group by per row.

Summing will remove the rows its sums over and only display the sum itself. So you have to group by some variable to make it split the results over that variables 'occurence'

Comment: He says that when he adds sum to quantite he only gets one row, so he is probably already doing this.

Comment: Yes it gets only one row quantite event I added SUM(IF(condition,quantite,0)). So I have to add it in reader.read() loop.
How ever your anwser has showed all rows but not the sum. So I do it in the loop. Thanks for attention.

Comment: After adding proper column name to GROUP BY and added same condition  written in "VenteWhere" to SUM(IF(VenteWhere, quantite,0 )) it worked. I don't know why it does not work with the WHERE condition only and need for the sum too.